How to Display Parent Widgets (App Bar and Bottom Navigation) in Child Screens Using GetX Navigation in Flutter?
I'm developing a Flutter app using the GetX package for state management and navigation. In my app, I have a main screen with an app bar and a bottom navigation bar. I'm using GetPages for routing and navigation. Here's a simplified version of my code:
GetPage(
  name: Routes.MAIN_SCREEN,
  page: () => const MainScreen(),
  binding: MainControllerBinding(),
  children: [
    GetPage(
      name: Routes.TIME_LINE,
      page: () => const TimelineScreen(),
      binding: TimelineControllerBinding(),
    ),
  ],
)

In this setup, when I navigate to the TimelineScreen, I want the app bar and bottom navigation bar from the MainScreen to be displayed there as well. This is similar to how  works in Angular for displaying child components within a parent component.
How can I achieve this functionality using GetX navigation in Flutter? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
